# Regex string modifications

Tags: java, regex, oop

I have the following String and I want to filter the `MBRB1045T4G` out with a regular expression in Java. How would I achieve that?

**String:**

```
<p class="ref">
<b>Mfr Part#:</b>
MBRB1045T4G<br>


<b>Technologie:</b>&nbsp;
    Tab Mount<br>



<b>Bauform:</b>&nbsp;
    D2PAK-3<br>



<b>Verpackungsart:</b>&nbsp;
    REEL<br>



<b>Standard Verpackungseinheit:</b>&nbsp;
    800<br>
```

Comment: [by offering up your sanity to Cthulhu](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html)

Comment: iow, use an HTML parser.

Comment: Please refrain from parsing HTML with RegEx as it will [drive you insane](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Use an [HTML parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292926/robust-mature-html-parser-for-php) instead.

Comment: What is your constraint? The second line after <p class="ref">? Something which starts at beginning of lińe with an uppercase letter? Something which ends with 4G? Something, 3 lines before Technologie?

Comment: basically before the String I want there is the </b> and then the <br> ... so its </b>STRING<br> but there is a line break between the </b> in the html, is that relevant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Wrikken correctly says, HTML can't be parsed correctly by regex in the general case. However it seems you're looking at an actual website and want to scrape some contents. In that case, assuming space elements and formatting in the HTML code don't change, you can use a regex like this:

```
 Mfr Part#:</b>([^<]+)<br>
```

And collect the first capture group like so (where `string` is your HTML):

```
Pattern pt = Pattern.compile("Mfr Part#:</b>\s+([^<]+)<br>",Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher m = pt.matcher(string); 
if (m.matches())
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
```

Comment: Pattern pt = Pattern.compile("Mfr Part#:</b>([^<]+)<br>"; ? How would I get the string?

Comment: Matcher m = pt.matcher(string); if (m.matches()) System.out.println(m.group(1));

Comment: Element desc = doc.select("p[class=ref]").first();
    logger.debug("found ref:"+ desc.text());
    Pattern pt = Pattern.compile("Mfr Part#:</b>([^<]+)<br>");
    Matcher m = pt.matcher(desc.text()); 
    if (m.matches()){
     logger.debug("found partnumber:"+ m.group(1));
     article.setManufacturerArticleNumber(m.group(1));
     article.setDistributorArticleNumber(m.group(1));
    }